# ConcurrentModificationException during putting new element into HashMap

Tags: java, concurrentmodificationexception

I have some code:

```
Map<String, Integer> letters = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
letters.put(String.valueOf(input.charAt(0)),
            numberOfLettersInWord(input,input.charAt(0)));
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
   for (String key : letters.keySet()) {
      if (!letters.containsKey(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)))) {
         letters.put(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)),
                     numberOfLettersInWord(input,input.charAt(i)));
      } else continue;
      System.out.println(letters);
   }
   System.out.println(1);
}
System.out.println(2);
```

The main idea in the code - there is some word in String input(not empty, not null, with no non-letter symbols), need to count how many times each letter can be found there.  Counting works OK (in the `numberOfLettersInWord` method) but when I try to add letters and digits to `HashMap<String, Integer>` some problems happens - it adds all letters and their numbers correctly but some error pops up.   For this code it will show:

```
1
1
{a=4, b=4}
1
1
1
1
{a=4, b=4, c=3}
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1579)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1602)
    at LetterCounter.count(LetterCounter.java:25)
    at LetterCounter.main(LetterCounter.java:11)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

From what I see there is something happens when there are no new letters to be added.  Can you explain why this happens and how to solve this?

It supposed to have some more digit outputs after the `{a=4, b=4, c=3}` was shown but it ends with the exception (it is not really necessary, just an indicator where it stops working...)

The word used in this run was `String input = "aabbabcccba";`

`numberOfLettersInWord` returns `Integer` value of how many times letter `input.charAt(i)` was found in word `input`(this works ok)

line 2 in code fragment was used just to make the `HashMap` contain at least one line (null and empty checks already done by this moment and work well)

I saw people had problems with `hashmap.remove()` in [Why is a ConcurrentModificationException thrown and how to debug it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/why-is-a-concurrentmodificationexception-thrown-and-how-to-debug-it) but I am not sure this is the same-same thing that can be solved with that answer.
Also I am not sure this answer is applicable for my case [ConcurrentModificationException - HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921250/concurrentmodificationexception-hashmap)

Comment: You have a `for (String key : letters.keySet())` loop, which is iterating the map. Inside this loop you have calls to `put` in the same map. This is illegal; you cannot modify a `HashMap` while iterating over its keys/values/entries. That said, I don't understand why you're iterating over the keys in the first place, as you don't appear to use `key` anywhere.

Comment: about `for (String key : letters.keySet())` - the idea was to keep letters and digits in array, where one letter wont be repeated and will have some integer number assigned to it. i checked how i can do this and used HashMap as a thing that can totally to what i needed. i read that to check all elements by key value i need to use that `for (String key : letters.keySet())` and in fact i have no idea how to replace it in current variant.. if i cant use that put inside this map will it be correct to make one more map with same data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i think i solved it:

```
Map<String, Integer> letters = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
letters.put(String.valueOf(input.charAt(0)),numberOfLettersInWord(input,input.charAt(0)));
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
   letters.putIfAbsent(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)),numberOfLettersInWord(input,input.charAt(i)));
}
```

i removed some extra code and it started work, even all tests passed

Comment: Glad you could get it to work :). But shouldn't that compute-if-absent call look more like `computeIfAbsent(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)), key -> numberOfLettersInWord(input, key))`? I believe what you have in the answer should be failing to compile, unless `numberOfLettersInWord` is returning a `Function`.

Comment: `numberOfLettersInWord` returns only Integer digit , after this code i just use letters to check that results i got are acceptable ror my task. not sure `computeIfAbsent` is ok for this case... i have word of `input.length()`, i'm cheching that its letters are added into `letters` in one copy and add how many times this letter is present in word

Comment: `computeIfAbsent` is essentially the same as `if (!containsKey)` -> `put`, which is what you have in your question, so that should be fine. My issue is that the second argument to `computeIfAbsent` must be a `Function` (which I implement as a lambda expression in my previous comment), but you're apparently passing an `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

## Why the ConcurrentModificationException?

You're getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` because you are structurally modifying the map while iterating its key set.

### Documentation

Here's what [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) of `HashMap` says on the subject:

> The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are *fail-fast*: if the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own `remove` method, the iterator will throw a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

Those "collection view methods" it mentions are the following:

1. `HashMap#keySet()`, which returns a `Set<K>`.
2. `HashMap#values()`, which returns a `Collection<V>`.
3. `HashMap#entrySet()`, which returns a `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>>`.

##### For-Each Loops

If you aren't aware, a for-each loop uses an `Iterator` behind the scenes. In other words, something like this:

```java
List<String> list = List.of("one", "two", "three");
for (String element : list) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Is compiled down to:

```java
List<String> list = List.of("one", "two", "three");
for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    String element = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

### Your Code

You have a for-each loop iterating over the key set of your map. Inside this for-each loop you have a call to `put`, which is a structurally-modifying operation, on the same map.

> ```java
> for (String key : letters.keySet()) {
>    if (!letters.containsKey(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)))) {
>       letters.put(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)),
>                   numberOfLettersInWord(input,input.charAt(i)));
>    } else continue;
>    System.out.println(letters);
> }
> ```

Thus, a `ConcurrentModificationException` is likely to be thrown. In your case it's all but guaranteed.

---

## Solution

You are apparently trying to count the frequencies of each letter in a string. This does not require you to loop over the key set of the map. The fact you don't actually use the `key` variable anywhere inside the for-each loop is a good indicator of this. This means you can simply get rid of the for-each loop and your code should work just fine.

```java
Map<String, Integer> letters = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
letters.put(String.valueOf(input.charAt(0)), numberOfLettersInWord(input,input.charAt(0)));
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    if (!letters.containsKey(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)))) {
        letters.put(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)), numberOfLettersInWord(input,input.charAt(i)));
    }
}
```

Note that call to `put` if the map does not already contain the key could be replaced with a call to [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)). That method takes the key and a `Function` that computes the value if the key is not already contained in the map (or if the key is currently mapped to `null`). It would look something like this:

```java
Map<String, Integer> letters = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
letters.put(String.valueOf(input.charAt(0)), numberOfLettersInWord(input,input.charAt(0)));
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    letters.computeIfAbsent(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)), key -> numberOfLettersInWord(input, key));
}
```

<sup>***Note:** The second argument the above `computeIfAbsent` call is a `Function` implemented via a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).*</sup>

### Potential Improvements

There may be a couple of improvements you could make to your code.

#### Change Key Type to Character

Given you're counting the frequency of *characters*, it would make sense to represent that in the code by using a `Map<Character, Integer>` instead of a `Map<String, Integer>`.

#### Count as You Go

I can only assume that `numberOfLettersInWord` loops over the input string and counts how many times the given character occurs in said string. This means you loop over the string for each character in the string, resulting in an inefficient algorithm. Though you do have optimization where you only compute the frequency of a character if you haven't already done so for that character, so that improves things a little.

However, you're already looping over all the characters in the input string. You might as well count the frequency of each character as you go. It could look something like:

```java
String input = ...;

Map<Character, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    Character key = input.charAt(i);

    Integer value = frequencies.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        frequencies.put(key, 1);
    } else {
        frequencies.put(key, value + 1);
    }
}
```

##### Use `compute` to Count

The body of that `for` loop can be replaced with a call to [`compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)):

```java
String input = ...;

Map<Character, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    frequencies.compute(input.charAt(i), (key, value) -> {
        if (value == null) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return value + 1;
        }
    });
}
```

And that lambda expression (implementing a `BiFunction`) can be "simplified" even more:

```java
(key, value) -> value == null ? 1 : value + 1
```

##### Use `merge` to Count

Another option is to use [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)):

```java
frequencies.merge(input.charAt(i), 1, Integer::sum);
```

<sup>***Note:** The `Integer::sum` is a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) implementing a `BiFunction`.*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

letters.keySet() is returning a set which is backed by the keys of the HashMap, which you then alter by calling put(). So the conflict here is between the keySet and the keys of the map. You would need to use an iterator, or extract the keys into a separate collection, by copying the keySet each time through the outer loop. Honestly, the algorithm is sounding kind of expensive, though I haven't really tried to work out a better approach...

Comment: `Map<String, Integer> letters = new HashMap<String, Integer>();` can maximum contain 52 lines with letter and digit, also it is just a training exercise without task to make algorithm cheap and it mostly focused on JUnit

Comment: "_You would need to use an iterator_" -- The for-each loop uses an `Iterator` behind the scenes, which is precisely where the `ConcurrentModificationException` is coming from.

Comment: well, `putIfAbsent` also worked for me. need more practice, i didnt know about that one before i asked here - needed more understanding why it is not working good after some number of iterations